# How to remove thousand comma separator in calculated column that returns text

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

How do I update "`=IF([Created Quarter]=1,YEAR(Created)+1,YEAR(Created))`" so that the result is, for example, 2016 instead of 2,016? "Created Quarter" is another calculated column that displays numbers 1, 2, 3, or 4.  I tried working in ISNUMBER but I think I'm using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your answer in =TEXT(yournumber, "0")

```
=IF([Created Quarter]=1,TEXT(YEAR(Created)+1,"0"),TEXT(YEAR(Created),"0"))
```